# JavaScript: Split objects in array based on space in object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, object

In JavaScript, let's say I have an array like this:

`[{display:"Foo"},{display:"Bar", field: {"Baz"}},{display:{"Baz Foo"}},{display: "Foo Bar", field: "Bar"}]`

and want to convert it into this:

`[{display:"Foo"},{display:"Bar", field: {"Baz"}},{display:{"Baz"}},{display:{"Foo"}},{display: "Foo", field: "Bar"},{display: "Bar", field: "Bar"}]`.

In other words, split the objects that contain space in the display field into two objects and keep the field property as it is.

I feel like it should be some simple solution to this, but I just don't get it right. Does anyone know how I can achieve this ?

Comment: You can write logic for this. SO is not the correct platform, to ask for logic. If you face any problem in logic, or if your logic doesn't work correctly, then you should ask here.

Comment: @Anita Where do you get this from? I really thought that to get help solving programming logic was just what SO was for, so I'm interested in reading where this is stated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```js
const input = [
  {display:"Foo"},
  {display:"Bar", field: "Baz"},
  {display:"Baz Foo"},
  {display:"Foo Bar", field: "Bar"}
]

const output = input.map((entry) =>
  entry.display.split(/\s+/g).
    map((part) => ({...entry, display: part}))
).flat()

console.log(output)
```

Note that `split(/\s+/g)` splits at one or more white-spaces, e.g. `"hello    world"` results in `["hello", "world"]`. If you do not want this, change to `split(" ")`, the result would then be `["hello", "", "", "", "world"]`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
const arr = [{display:"Foo"},{display:"Bar", field: "Baz"},{display:"Baz Foo"},{display: "Foo Bar", field: "Bar"}]

const newArr = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const { field, display } = cur
  const newObjs = display.split(" ").map(dis => ({ display: dis, field }));
  acc = acc.concat(newObjs)
  return acc
}, [])
```